# Measure string as if it would be on html?

Tags: c#, html, graphics, drawing

I have the exact string : <kbd>123..</kbd>

I want to see what its length would be as *if it was on a Html page* ( as SPAN)

```
font-name:arial
font-size:16px;
```

I made an experiment :

http://jsbin.com/axezib/edit#preview

so

```
<span style="font-family:arial;border:solid 1px red;display:inline-block;font-size:16px;">123..</span>
```

is rendered to :

[image]

and its properties :

<kbd>ofcourse   *
  {
    padding:0px;margin:0px;
  }</kbd>

[image]

as you can see its width is 35 and height=19. ( *lets ignore the border* ...)

however I have this code which should (*or not*) tell me the same result :

```
void Main( )
      {
     string input = "123..";
     FontFamily fontFamily = new FontFamily("Arial");
     Font testFont = new  Font(   fontFamily,   16, FontStyle.Regular,   GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
     Size s = TextRenderer.MeasureText(input, testFont);
     Console.WriteLine("Size: height " + s.Height + ", width " + s.Width);
     Console.ReadLine();
      }
```

however the result is :

[image]

what am I missing here ?

Thanks <kbd>:-)</kbd>

## edit

after [re-editing](http://jsbin.com/axezib/2/edit#javascript,html) the html code by adding a CSS RESET  - the code is rendered exactly in all 4 browsers.
so the question remains - why the c# doesnt show me the same result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems as if you are trying to compare the size of a string rendered with default Windows font rendering (and any anti-aliasing, ClearType settings etc that are default on your system) and compare that to the rendering done by browsers on Windows which may or may not have **their own font rendering engines**. As far as I know, Gecko (Firefox) and Webkit (Chrome, Safari) implement their own font rendering so they can present HTML/CSS consistently across different platforms.

So basically, even if you could get your C# code to agree, the result is fairly meaningless as you are comparing apples and oranges! See "Current Implementations" in [this article](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/04/24/a-closer-look-at-font-rendering/).

Answer (score 2):

You may solve this puzzle for this particular web browser, but you won't be able to measure the string for all browsers available. Even worse, there are many operating systems, video cards, languages, font versions and display settings. This produces zillion combinations displaying text a little bit different.

If you're testing your web app, run a web browser from your C# code (IE, for example), load your webpage and get DOM node measurements from there. This is the only way you can obtain real-world values.

Also, there are a lot of testing toolkits that will simplify this task for you.

Comment: well , after reading your answer and seeing this : http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/ - i got a css which **made their size equal in all 4 browsers ( tested by me now !)** . so this solve the problem of rendering issue. what about the c# code ? you are welcome to see it http://jsbin.com/axezib/2/edit#preview